# WebSites can't access to Sql Server DBs while recycling Application pool

Tags: sql-server, iis-7.5, application-pools

I have some websites hosted on IIS7.5 windows 2008 R2
sometimes I am notified that sites report an error on connection to DBs and can't connect to DB while sql server is running. Nothing changed on server.
If I restart web site still I get that error message. If I recycle the Application pool, web site can connect to DB again.

I used default setting for Application pool and just change it to work under Network service account. I didn't find any useful information on Windows Log or SQL server logs

How can I find the issue and fix it?

Comment: Error messages? Stack trace? You're question is too vague to answer in its current form.

Comment: the message is same as when DB's User name or password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

websites with this behavior are Dotnetnuke and I find that it's a problem in dotnetnuke and not related to sql server settings:
more details : 
http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/under-construction

Answer (score 1):

What version and edition of SQL Server are you running?

Check to make sure that the database property [AUTO_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190249.aspx) is set to FALSE.

Comment: I used SQL server 2008 R2 Express Ed. some db property Auto_Clost was set to true and I fix it